# operator call syntax in C++

Tags: c++, operators, comparison-operators

Whether there can be a situation where the syntax

```
if (first == second) // ...
```

is different from that?

```
if (first.operator==(second)) // ...
```

I don't think so, but just want to know it.

Answer (score 9):

```
a == b
```

is sometimes equivalent to

```
a.operator==(b)
```

and sometimes equivalent to

```
operator==(a,b)
```

and sometimes equivalent to neither, if the meaning ends up being the "built-in" meaning of `==` for non-class types.

Whenever the compiler sees `==`, if at least one type involves a user-defined type, it searches for member operators (must not be hidden in the scope of `a`'s class type) and non-member operators (using argument dependent lookup) and built-in meanings (since a class might have an implicit conversion to an ordinary type with built-in comparison).  If more than one could make sense, it goes to the rules for overload resolution.

Comment: Actually, if more than one is found, it goes to the rules for overload resolution. Name lookup is *extremely* dumb.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "when are the two syntaxes not equivalent", then the answer is when the equality operator is not a member of whatever type `first` is. Obviously the second variant will not work for types without a member `operator==`. That includes built-in types.

When a member operator does exist for the type of `first`, then the two differ because the non-member operator could allow type conversions for both `first` and `second`, whereas the example with the member operator can only allow a conversion for `second`.

Comment: Or when `first` is a built-in type.

Comment: @SethCarnegie right, in which case the second example wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

One illustration to a situation in which the two statement have different effects is where you  have implicit conversions of `first`. For example:

```
struct my_int
{
    int num;

    my_int(int num) : num(num) {}
};

bool operator==(const my_int& a, const my_int& b)
{
    return a.num == b.num;
}
```

In this case, the following is a valid C++ code:

```
my_int a(1);
int x = 1;

if (x == a) {
    std::cout << "Equal\n";
}
```

Where compiling this code:

```
my_int a(1);
int x = 1;

if (x.operator==(a)) {
    std::cout << "Equal\n";
}
```

Gives a compile error like the following:

> conversion.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: conversion.cpp:21:16: error:
>   request for member ‘operator==’ in ‘x’, which is of non-class type
>   ‘int’

Answer (score 0):

The second won't work with primitives. However, both forms will work with custom-built types who have that operator overloaded publicly.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is based on syntax alone, then it depends on the type of the parameters. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a {


public:

  a(){
  }

  int operator ==(const a& v){
    cout << "member operator" << endl;
    return false;
  }

};

int operator ==(a &v1, a &v2){
    cout << "external operator" << endl;
    return true;
}


int main(){

  a a1, a2;

  if (a1 == a2 && a1.operator==((const a&)a2)) {
    cout << "done" << endl;
  }

}
```

In this setting, both operators are being called. 
If the function type parameters are the same, it seems that the method will be prefered.

Comment: The reason `a1==a2` chooses the external operator is that its parameter `a& v2` is a better match for lvalue `a2` than parameter `const a& v`.  The `const` is important.

Comment: Of course, I was just demonstrating the possibility of a difference between both syntaxes. Depending on the function types, one syntax may generate a different call from the other.